# order in join alias table in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, join

```
$this->Message->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'users',
            'alias' => 'UserJoin',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'UserJoin.id = Message.from'
            ),
            **'order'=>'UserJoin.datetime DESC',
            'limit'=>1**
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Message.to' => 4
    ),
    'fields' => array('UserJoin.*', 'Message.*'),
    'order' => 'Message.datetime DESC'
));
```

i am trying to add order to join alias table,but didn't get the result

Comment: $this->Message->find('all', array( 'joins' => array( array( 'table' => 'users', 'alias' => 'UserJoin', 'type' => 'INNER', 'conditions' => array( 'UserJoin.id = Message.from' ), 'order'=>'UserJoin.datetime DESC', 'limit'=>1 ) ), 'conditions' => array( 'Message.to' => 4 ), 'fields' => array('UserJoin.', 'Message.'), 'order' => 'Message.datetime DESC' ));

Comment: welcome to SO .. have you tried setting the UserJoin-order in the `outer` order field, so

`'order' => array('Message.datetime' => 'DESC', 'UserJoin.datetime' => 'DESC')`

Comment: Is this a `OneToOne` connection or are you trying to find the most current entry in `UserJoin` altough there are multiple?

Comment: You may try to use order as array `'order' => array('Message.datetime`=>'DESC')`

Comment: i want to sort data inside join, here is change needed **'order'=>'UserJoin.datetime DESC',
            'limit'=>1**

Comment: that is not working  @ harpax

Comment: yes that i want but one to many relation-Mary